# When does the v3 Cosmos DB .NET SDK for NoSQL retry write requests?

Tags: .net, azure-cosmosdb

I have an application that attempts to upsert many documents to a manual throughput provision container using the v3 Cosmos DB .NET SDK for NoSQL. The cosmos account has a single write region configured.

I am getting 429 (Too Many Request Errors).

I am wondering what the best way to manage this is (i'd rather slow down the application than increase the container's throughput). Should I implement retry logic at the application level? Or has the SDK already retried?

This [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/best-practice-dotnet) says
"
The SDK has built-in logic to handle these transient failures on retryable requests like read or query operations. For accounts configured with a single write region, the SDK won't retry on writes for transient failures as writes aren't idempotent.
"

That article says the SDK won't retry on writes for TRANSIENT failures. Is a 429 (Too Many Requests) error considered a transient failure? I.e. the SDK won't retry the upsert and therefore I need to handle the retry at the application level?

Comment: error 429 is not "too many requests" - Cosmos DB doesn't have a maximum number of requests. For Cosmos DB, it represents a situation where you have exhausted your available Request Units for a given 1-second window (and the 429 result tells you how long you need to wait, in milliseconds, before you're clear to try your operation again).

Answer (score 0):

You should use the retry logic of the SDK. As you found in the documentation it handles transient errors; In other words errors that might soon resolve themselves. A `429` is a textbook example of that as your input is totally valid, but the backend can't handle it **at that moment**.

While you could implement your own logic there's a few reasons why you should leave it to the SDK. The people that implemented it (likely) have more knowledge what is a transient error and what is not. The SDK is aware of the `x-ms-retry-after-ms` header which specifies retries should wait a minimum amount of time, which avoids unnecessary traffic. And the SDK is well maintained should any features affect the retry logic.

While creating your `CosmosClient` you can also customize the options to suit your needs on the retry logic:

```cs
var options = new CosmosClientOptions()
{
    MaxRetryAttemptsOnRateLimitedRequests = 100,
    MaxRetryWaitTimeOnRateLimitedRequests = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The article you linked has a section for retries, that leads to: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/conceptual-resilient-sdk-applications#should-my-application-retry-on-errors

This covers the retries for each StatusCode, including 429:

> The Azure Cosmos DB SDKs will retry on HTTP 429 errors by default following the client configuration and honoring the service's response x-ms-retry-after-ms header, by waiting the indicated time and retrying after.

> When the SDK retries are exceeded, the error is returned to your application. Ideally inspecting the x-ms-retry-after-ms header in the response can be used as a hint to decide how long to wait before retrying the request. Another alternative would be an exponential back-off algorithm or configuring the client to extend the retries on HTTP 429.

Regardless of being a read or a write, 429s are retried up to a certain point that you can configure (or you can even build your own retry behavior).

The wording on https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/best-practice-dotnet is a bit obscure and needs improvement, but when it mentions Transient it meant to mention timeouts -> https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/conceptual-resilient-sdk-applications#timeouts-and-connectivity-related-failures-http-408503